# Social icons in footer inline with text

Tags: html, css

I'm student and very new at this.

I'm trying to get the text (footer_contact_text) in same line as my footer icons (social_icons). Tried with display in-block and float but it does not work as I want.

Trying to figure out what the problem is but i'm stuck.

Sorry for a lot of code :) hope you understand.

```css
/* Footer */

.grid_medium_footer{

 margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}


.footer_contact {
 
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
}


.footer_contact table {
 border: none;
}


.footer_contact th, td  {
 border: none;
 line-height: 16px;

}

ul.footer_contact_text{
 margin:0;
 list-style: none;
}

ul.footer_contact_text li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 20px;
 border-right: 2px solid #cdcdcd;
 line-height: 15px;

}

ul.footer_contact_text li:last-child{
 border-style: none;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #04fbc7;
 margin-right: 0px;
}

 
.footer_contact .social_icons {
 float:right;
 
}

.footer_contact ul.social_icons li {
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 margin-right: 38px;
      
}
.footer_contact ul.social_icons li a{
 text-indent: -99999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;;
    background-position: -16px -729px;
}
.footer_contact ul.social_icons li a.social_facebook{
    background-position: -65px -785px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.footer_contact ul.social_icons li a.social_twitter{
 background-position: -167px -785px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.footer_contact ul.social_icons li a.social_linkedin{
 background-position: -117px -785px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.footer_contact ul.social_icons li a.social_instagram{
 background-position: -17px -785px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}


.footer_contact a {
 color: #3c273a;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer_contact">
  <div class="grid_medium_footer">
   
  <div class="footer_icons">
   
            
          <ul class="social_icons">
               <li><a href="#" class="social_instagram     bgimgsprite">Instragram</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" class="social_facebook bgimgsprite">Facebook</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" class="social_linkedin bgimgsprite">Linkedin</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" class="social_twitter bgimgsprite">Twitter</a></li>
             </ul>
     </div>   
     <div class="fixfloat"></div> 
     
     
  <!--  Kontakt uppgifter statiska -->
      <ul class="footer_contact_text">    
   <li><?php echo (get_option('namn')); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo (get_option('gata')); ?></li>
   <li><?php echo (get_option('postnr')); ?></li>
   <li><?php echo (get_option('epost')); ?></li>
      </ul><br>
      
      <table>  
  <tr>  
     <th><?php echo (get_option('orgnr')); ?></th>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      </table>
     
      
   </div> <!-- grid_medium_footer --> 
 </div>   <!--footer_contact -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a parent `<div>` and put 2 other `<div>` inside it.
Like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
    Texts here...
  </div>

  <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
    Icons here...
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because images are inline elements, you can set their `vertical-align` property to `middle` - that way they'll sit vertically aligned next to your text. Here's a quick example:

```
<div class="social">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-icons-the-circle-set/48/facebook_circle-512.png" width="24" height="24" /> Facebook
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-icons-the-circle-set/48/facebook_circle-512.png" width="24" height="24" /> Facebook
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
}

img {
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
}

</style>
```

You can see it on CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBYpjL)